# Allow Form1 to close without closing Application in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-c#-express-2010

Ok, form1 is my "intro". I need form1 to close and form2...When it closes, the Whole application closes. I am new at this, so i do not know how to explain my problems well...If you have any question..please ask... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution which I use when I need to have a splash screen before showing the main form is to use this solution:

In the Main function of your Program class you usually have something like that:

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] ps)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());

    }
```

The Application.Run bind the application to a form so that when the form closes, the application exit.
If you want to show form 2 before form 1, you can do this:

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] ps)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Form1 splash = new Form1();
        splash.ShowDialog();
        Application.Run(new Form2());
    }
```

This new code will show form2. and after you close form2, it will show form1. Closing Form1 will exit the application.

Usually the Splash window is created in another thread, leaving the main thread loading the data it needs.

Comment: Good and Intellegent Answer! +1

Comment: ok, but is there a way that when i close form1, form2 can become form1 or become the main form...i have already done mo0st of the program, and i just need a code to change the main form to form2...good answer though!

Comment: I don't understand. There should be one main form which is the one you pass to the run method. Any other form should be shown using either the ShowDialog method (Modal form) or the Show method. Btw, using this method, only 1 form is shown at a given time. First Form2 then Form1

Comment: I think I swaped the form names, Form1 should be the splash form. Code updated.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of closing you can hide From1.

```
Form1.hide = true
```

Comment: well, can i just close the form, then allow the other form be the main form...i would prefer that method, but good answer!

Answer (score 0):

You should override the OnClosing method in the form...

```
protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
{
     e.Cancel = true;
     this.Hide();
}
```